# Angular Datepicker minDate and maxDate is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I am trying to inject angular js datepicker into my project. i am done according to documentation. but there is nothing appear to visible date picker.
I have created a plnkr [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2?p=preview)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker/master/app/styles/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker/master/dist/angular-datepicker.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.4.1/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.6.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker/master/app/scripts/datePicker.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker/master/app/scripts/datePickerUtils.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker/master/app/scripts/dateRange.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker/master/app/scripts/input.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input class="form-control" date-time ng-model="DateOfbirth" max-date="today" view="date" timezone="UTC" format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm">
  </body>

</html>
```

doc ref. [here](https://rawgit.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker/master/app/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

try to upgrade angular version to 1.5.X

some of the features that max/min date needed not includes in the lowest

angular versions.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by adding custom `$watch`.

```
$scope.$watch('addUserProfileData.DateOfbirth', validate_dateOfbirth);

    function validate_dateOfbirth () {

        if ( $scope.addUserProfileData.DateOfbirth != "" ) {

            var selectedDate = moment($scope.addUserProfileData.DateOfbirth.toISOString()).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
            var current_date = moment(moment().toISOString()).format('DD/MM/YYYY');

            var momentA = moment(selectedDate,"DD/MM/YYYY");
            var momentB = moment(current_date,"DD/MM/YYYY");

            if (momentA >= momentB) {

                $scope.addUserProfileForm.DateOfbirth.$setValidity("endBeforeStart", false);
            } else {
                $scope.addUserProfileForm.DateOfbirth.$setValidity("endBeforeStart", true);
            }
        }

    }
```